# Python Sets vs Hash table Performance for List Comparison Algorithm

Tags: python, time-complexity

I was under the impression that sets in Python were implemented using hash tables. However, in the code below, the sets-based version performs much better than the hash-table version. I guess the sets implementation is quite different to what I've done in `count_common_elements_hash_table()`. Can anyone please explain the difference in performance?

```
import random
import time
import decimal

def count_common_elements_sets(l1, l2):
    common_elements = set(l1).intersection(l2)
    return len(common_elements)


def count_common_elements_hash_table(l1, l2):
    table = {}
    common_elements = []
    for v in l1:
        table[v] = True
    count = 0
    for w in l2:
        if table.get(w):  # Avoid KeyError that would arise with table[w]
            common_elements.append(w)
            count += 1
    return count


l1 = [random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(1000)]
l2 = [random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(1000)]



# Time execution
start = time.perf_counter()
count_common_elements_hash_table(l1, l2)
end = time.perf_counter()
print("Hash table version: {:.7f}".format(end - start))

# Time execution
start = time.perf_counter()
count_common_elements_sets(l1, l2)
end = time.perf_counter()
print("Sets version: {:.7f}".format(end - start))
```

Comment: Because you are using the built-in `.intersection` method on `set` objects. With your `dict` implementation, you are basically getting the intersection, but it is in Python. The `set.intersection` method implemented in C. Built-in functions / methods will almost always be faster than equivalent algorithms that get executed at the python interpreter level